# Show message is user is in active mode while login laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$credentials = [
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'active'   => 1, //active
];

//Message if user in active user trying to logged in "This user is inactive mode conact to admin"

if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
    //logged in
}else{
    //Error
}
```

It should return a message if user in active user trying to logged in "This user is inactive mode conact to admin"
How can we check Auth::attempt exception error please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't get your concern. You want to check if active flag is 1 or 0 after logging in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please code like this 
First check if credentials are correct then check active status

```
 $credentials = [
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];


if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->active == 1) {
      // Login successfully
    } else {
      return error for inactive
    }
}else{
    //Error
}
```

Comment: No i want to check while login if credentials are correct but user is inactive it should display inactive user

Answer (score 0):

```
$credentials = [
'email' => Input::get('email'),
'password' => Input::get('password'),
'active'   => 1, //active
];
```

//Message if user in active user trying to logged in "This user is 
   inactive mode conact to admin"

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

       if(Auth::user()->active == 1) {
          // Login successfully
       } else {
          return back()->with('error','your account is inactive');
       }
}else{
  return back()->with('error','user is inactive');
}
```

now in your view page

```
  @if(Session::has('error'))
    {{Session::get('error')}}
  @endif
```